# Why can't I access the security section in web admin to edit my user roles?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-administration

I have been going in circles trying to fix this.  This is the error message I receive...

There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Server cannot access application directory 'H:\Login\'. The directory does not exist or is not accessible because of security settings.

Comment: Looks like you have all the information you need to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically a permissions problem.

Go to the listed directory on your server. If the directory exists, make sure that the iis user and/or app user have the required permissions to that directory.

Comment: Thanks very much! Sorted :) Managed to get it working!